# Figuring out MFG

Tags: moment-generating-functions

Let X have a Poisson distribution with parameter L(short for lambda here )

show that the MGF function of Y=(x-L)/sqrt(L) is given by

m(t) = exp(lamda*e^(t/sqrt(lamda)) - sqrt(lamda)t - lamda)

Here's what I did:

My(t)=E(e^Yt)
     =E[e^(t(x-L)/sqrt(L))]
     =and some more expansion, so what now ? I've read wiki and wolfmen already.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: I tried , but still cant get the form right

Comment: Use the Law of the unconscious statistician, factor out all terms that do not involve your summation index, rewrite the series into the form of the series for $e^{x}$ and replace the series with the exponential.